# BeautifulSoup: the table element is not detected at all times; 'NoneType' error is returned sometimes

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, nonetype

Hey all I want to get actual daily temperatures from [www.wunderground.com](https://wundergound.com) and have been running into the 'NoneType' error from time to time. *E.g.*, below is a piece of code that tries to get the temperature from March 1 to March 5, 2020. There are times where I am able to get results for the first couple of days, but there are also times where the code broke **at the step of getting the summary table**, *i.e.*, it is not able to find the table with the class attribute of "ng-star-inserted."

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
df = {'date':[], 'daily average temperature':[]}
while day <= 5:
    daily_weather_url = "https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/KBOS/date/2020-3-" + str(day)
    driver.get(daily_weather_url)
    content = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

    summary_table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "ng-star-inserted"})
    summary_table_rows=summary_table.find_all("tr")

    average_temp=summary_table_rows[3].find_all("td")[0].text.strip()

    df['date'].append("2020-3-"+str(day))
    df['daily average temperature'].append(average_temp)

    day += 1 
    time.sleep(30)

driver.close()
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df)
```

I wonder if this is caused by the fact that the wunderground.com server is defensive and wouldn't let users scrape. But its robots.txt seems to suggest that scraping is okay with a crawl-delay of 10 sec. How can I resolve this error? Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your request headers, I did and the scrape loop worked just fine, I used webdriver.FireFox() but it should not make a difference:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
df = {'date':[], 'daily average temperature':[]}
day = 1
while day <= 5:
    daily_weather_url = "https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/KBOS/date/2020-3-" + str(day)
    driver.header_overrides = {
    "Host": "www.wunderground.com",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "TE": "Trailers"
    } 
    driver.get(daily_weather_url)
    content = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

    summary_table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "ng-star-inserted"})
    summary_table_rows=summary_table.find_all("tr")

    average_temp=summary_table_rows[3].find_all("td")[0].text.strip()

    df['date'].append("2020-3-"+str(day))
    df['daily average temperature'].append(average_temp)

    day += 1 
    time.sleep(10)

driver.close()
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df)
```

[image]